# Real part of a complex expression on unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For what $A$ and $\beta$, we have
$$\Re\Big(Az^2-(1-\beta)z\Big)\geqslant0 \,\,\,\, , \,\,\, |z|<1$$
which $A$ is a complex number and $\beta$ is so, such that $|\beta|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z) = Az^2-(1-\beta)z$ is holomorphic in the unit disk $\Bbb D$, 
and $f(0) = 0$.

If $f$ is not constant then it is an *open mapping* and maps a small neighbourhood of $z= 0$ to a neighbourhood of $f(z) = 0$,
therefore $\Re f(z) \ge 0$ for all $z \in \Bbb D$ cannot be satisfied.

Another possible argument is that $u(z) = \Re f(z)$ is *harmonic*
and satisfies the maximum principle.

So the only solution would be the trivial one: $f$ is identically zero,
i.e. $A = 0$ and $\beta = 1$. With your condition $|\beta|<1$
there is no solution at all.